# Would it be reasonable for a small internal application to have the ASP.NET application and a IIS server in the same machine?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am new to the Microsoft world coming from a Java mindset.

For a Java-based web application usually we would have a Database/Data server, one or several Application Server(s) hosting the application and an HTTP server (Apache ETC) on top of the Application Server.

As I can understand the IIS is both an application container and an fully fledged HTTP server. Would it be reasonable for a small (1-80 users) internal application to have the ASP.NET application and the IIS server functioning as an HTTP Server in the same machine?

Is it usually done that way?

Comment: Actually it is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way, and the answer may become self-evident:

IIS, at it's core in an architectural sense, is a web server. Components such as ASP.NET are, in effect, custom request *handlers* or *extensions* to the core web server functionality. As a result, it would be more than reasonable to see a single IIS installation host perhaps *mulitple* ASP.NET applications, and perhaps multiple more conventional static websites.

I think your use case is actually the basic model for IIS, and is thus entirely reasonable.